# jQuery Wrap innerHTML

Tags: jquery, html

i have html like this

```
<a href="#">like me on facebook</a>
```

and i want to wrap the text facebook so the result will be like this

```
<a href="#">like me on <span class="facebook-text">facebook</span></a>
```

how to do that in jQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var html = $('a').html();
$('a').html(html.replace(/facebook/, '<span class="facebook-text">facebook</span>'));
```

and if you want to replace all occurrences of facebook within the string:

```
var html = $('a').html();
$('a').html(html.replace(/facebook/gi, '<span class="facebook-text">facebook</span>'));
```

Comment: did replace() is jQuery API? i looking for explanation of `replace()` in api.jquery.com but cannot find it

Comment: @GusDe CooL, no, it is [plain 'ol javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use the $(...).contents() function to access the child nodes of your anchor tag.

http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: This may not answer the op's question, but it did solve my problem. The following sample should wrap the entire contents, not just the text "facebook": `$('a').contents().wrap('<span class="facebook-text">')`